# Renaming all folder name using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to rename folder name using batch script ? I need to rename file name like:

```
a Filename1
b filename2 
to
A
B
```

i.e make it uppercase and substring only to initial part.
So far I have come up with :

```
@echo "Renaming file"
for /D %%f in (C:\REN\*) do rename "%%f" "%%~nxf_myname"
pause
```

Comment: So you want to take only the first character and convert to uppercase? Please specify the _exact_ renaming pattern...

Comment: So which is it? Do you want to rename folders or files?

Comment: @EitanT I want to rename only letters before space to caps and remove other letter after space including space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you actually want to rename folders found in C:\REN\, and not files.

I'm also assuming that by "initial part" you mean up until the first space character. If this is correct, then you want to use FOR /F to parse the name into tokens.

The SET search and replace functionality is case insensitive with regard to the search portion.

I'm creating variables for both the original and new names and I'm toggling delayed exapnsion on and off just in case the folder name contains a `!` character. For variables are corrupted if value contains `!` and delayed expansion is enabled.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
echo Renaming folders
for /d %%F in (C:\REN\*) do (
  for /f "eol= " %%A in ("%%~nxF") do (
    set "name=%%F"
    set "newName=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for %%C in (
        A B C D E F G H I J K L M
        N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
    ) do set "newName=!newName:%%C=%%C!"
    ren "!name!" "!newName!"
    endlocal
  )
)
```